# Efficient way of changing a lot of mysql column names

Tags: php, mysql

I have an existing database and I have now decided to use Red Bean. One of the requirements is that column names have to be lowercase and not contain any special characters.

This means I have 1,500+ column names to change

For example, Client_ID needs to change to clientid

What is the most efficient way to achieve this with a large number of columns?

My initial thoughts are

- run a query to gather existing column names from information_schema
- convert the column name to lowercase and strip out special characters
- run a query to update these columns

Is there a more efficient method?

Comment: Although the requirements are sensible, but to use redbean would be a VERY BAD idea. This program is against almost every good practice and all you will do is shoot yourself in the foot

Comment: that said, you'd have it much faster your way than waiting for some "more efficient method" making it deliberately less efficient

Comment: Is there any way to make Red Bean just deal? I know many ORMs have a "thanks but no thanks" option to naming conventions.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no "efficient" way here. You must carefully convert all these names from one form to another. You must also update any code that references these names. Usually this involves a lot of very precise search and replace and a hefty database migration script. Keep in mind you'll want to be able to undo this change in a pinch, so having a backup you can restore to, or an inverse 'undo rename' script is great to have on hand.

Comment: Depending on the size, you could make a backup and use a text editor to to change it.if the database is too big you can program a tool when teh renaming follows rules, taht can be put to code